# Group with 6 elements and one element not specified directly

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have to solve, but don't understand what "c" is!

Description:
It exists a Group G with exactly 6 elements $a, b, c, d, e, f$. with $a^2=b^2=d^2=d$,  $e^2=f$, $ab=e$.

Now I totally don't know what $c$ is.
I got a hint, that the requirements would define what $c$ is, so because $G$ is a group there has to exist a inverse Element and a neutral Element. Unfortunately, to my interpretation, $c$ is neither of those. What is c?

Comment: The element c is the element in the group other than the elements a,b,d,e,f on which you know something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement $d^2=d$ tells you that $d$ is the identity of the group.  Then $a$ and $b$ are self inverses, so this is not the cyclic group of order $6$ because that has only one element that is a self inverse.  The order of $e$ has to divide $6$ and it can't be $2$, so it must be $3$ and $e^3=d$ and $f^3=e^6=d=ef$  This looks like [$S_3$, the symmetric group on three elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group), so see if you can make the elements correspond to the multiplication table of that.

Comment: Hey, thank you verry much. 
Here is my element chart corresponding this [$S_3$ Chart](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_(Gruppe)):
https://i.imgur.com/qqHEAJQ.png


I hope i didnt miss anythinng.

Comment: $f^{-1}$would than be $f$, because $f$ is inverse to hisself. Correct?

Comment: No, $f^{-1}=e,$ as $ef=d$